# How do I make this border round in conky Manjaro KDE? (Repost from "off topic" StackOverflow post)

Tags: linux, manjaro, conky

**Origanaly posted by RodrigoSQL on StackOverflow. I answered this question on StackOverflow but it was deleted**

How do I make this border round?

Hello guys, I'm setting up Conky in the manjaro, but I would like to know if it is possible to leave the rounded corners indicated in the image Below enter image description here

My config:

```
--[[
# Minimalis Conky 1.3
# Author : archit3x
# Release date : 4 December 2020
# Tested on : Archlinux ARM - XFCE Desktop
# Email : archit3x@archlinux.us
# Feel free to modity this script ;)
]]

conky.config = {
    alignment = 'top_right',
    background = true,
    border_width = 1,
    cpu_avg_samples = 2,
    default_color = 'gray',
    default_outline_color = 'white',
    default_shade_color = 'white',
    color1 = '#1793d1',
    double_buffer = true,
    draw_borders = yes,
    draw_graph_borders = true,
    draw_outline = false,
    draw_shades = false,
    extra_newline = false,
    xftalpha = 0.5,
    draw_shades = true,
    default_shade_color = 'black',
    gap_x = 6,
    gap_y = 38,
    minimum_height = 250,
    minimum_width = 220,
    net_avg_samples = 2,
    no_buffers = true,
    out_to_console = false,
    out_to_ncurses = false,
    out_to_stderr = false,
    out_to_x = true,
    own_window = true,
    own_window_class = 'conky',
    own_window_transparent = yes,
    own_window_argb_visual = true,
    own_window_argb_value = 170,
    own_window_type = 'Conky',
    own_window_hints ='undecorated,sticky,below, skip_taskbar',
    show_graph_range = false,
    show_graph_scale = true,
    stippled_borders = 1,
    update_interval = 0.9,
    uppercase = false,
    use_spacer = 'false',
    use_xft = true,
    font = 'Fantasque Sans normal:size=9',
    
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not appear to be possible with Minimalis Conky because `conky.conf` can't have a border option (all possible config lines).

- You can round borders if you use lua, [see here](https://www.gnome-look.org/p/1384943/) for example.
- [Here](https://www.unixmen.com/install-conky-lua-ubuntu-14-0413-1013-04-debian-fedora-linux-mint-opensuse/) is an article on how to get lua working with Conky.

If you don't want to go and find the radius setting your self in the `.lua` file use the example theme I linked to above.